# Is there any way with DevExpress to explicitly set the IDs of objects?

Tags: selenium, devexpress, watir, web-testing

I am testing a new web page being developed with DevExpress.  The object Ids (html ids) all come out as random strings with no tie to what they are identifying.

ie:
    a class="dxm-content dxm-hasText dx " href="/CR/SDPersonellHomePage" 
    id="HeaderMenu_DXI0i0_T" style="float: none;">
    span class="dx-vam">Summary Page /span>/a>

Is there any way to tell DevExpress to give this object a more meaningful ID?
Or add another parameter we can use to give readability to our test artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

With Watir you can use regular expressions to match the attributes if the pattern itself is unique. It's slower than an exact string, but much more flexible. For example:

```
browser.link(id: /HeaderMenu_\w{6}_T/)
browser.link(id: /HeaderMenu_\w{6}_T/, class: 'dx-vam')
browser.link(id: /HeaderMenu_\w{6}_T/, class: /^dx/)
browser.link(id: /^HeaderMenu_/, href: /PersonellHomePage$/)
```

Comment: That does not address the issue that the ID has no intelligence in it.  The ID could be reassigned to another object by DevExpress and we would be left scrambling.  We need the developers to force some logical name or suffix either in the Id or another parameter we can then point to.

Comment: So even the pattern is not unique. If you can add data attributes:
   `<p data-type=ruby-library>watir-webdriver</p>` Can be accessed with: `browser.p(:data_type => "ruby-library")`.

Comment: The pattern is Unique, but has no intelligence in it.  If another item is added to the menu this link is a member of, we can have no confidence that the ID will not change.  And if it does, only a tedious search will inform us of the new ID.  IDs should tell anyone looking at them what they are identifying, or they are of limited use.

Comment: Heh, I think I overlooked the most obvious option. Your text is going to stay the same: `browser.link(text: 'Summary Page')`

Comment: Ok, for the link example, we can do that.  But for all other object types we do not have that option.  A Text box cannot be identified thus.

Comment: Internally we use code that does things like: `browser.div(text: 'foo').previous_sibling` and 'browser.div(text: 'foo').parent.text_field` The sibling code isn't currently in Watir proper, but would something like that be useful to you?

Comment: Titus, It sounds useful.  I currently use the Page Object methodology so what I really need is the ability to cleanly id each object.

Comment: The sibling code is here if you want to monkey patch it- https://github.com/titusfortner/watir-webdriver/commit/06224309a6d765c83f355dcd6cdcf31310bee996 If you are referring to the page object gem, I am not a fan. It re-implements things that Watir does with much less flexibility. It definitely can do more than just id's, but it doesn't support all locators for all types of html5 elements, which Watir does innately.

Answer (score 0):

After several conversations with DevExpress support, They now claim they do not actually support Selenium and recommend using their own test engine.

On review that engine is barely better then a record and playback tool.
DevExpress explicitly stated they do not recommend using the 'Id' parameter for automated testing, and have to date not provided a way to add a custom parameter to use in its place.

At this point, I must recommend NOT using this tool if you plan to build any lasting automation tests.

I will update this if DevExpress replies with a viable solution.

Comment: I just got this reply from DevExpress:    Paul (DevExpress Support)4 minutes ago
Hi,

We thoroughly test our components before publishing and the design of our controls doesn't imply testing by our users. We don't support any 3rd party testing tools and aren't planning to support them in the near future because it will require total control redesign.

Comment: Does anyone else see a problem with this?

Comment: Ugh, record/playback testing is a horrible approach. It sounds like watir with text and regex using sibling & parent methods is your best option, even though it is far from ideal.